# Launch KEGGscape

Tags: app-store, launch, cytoscape, app-manager

I have installed KEGGscape into my Cytoscape 3.10.1. It is listed under "installed apps" in the App manager. I have enabled all apps. When I open Cytoscape and click on the tab at the top "Apps", it doesn't list KEGGscape. Is there another way I can open/launch the app without it being in that panel? Maybe in the App manager?

Answer (score 0):

When you install the keggscape app, it just adds a reader for kgml files, so there isn't anything in the apps menu.  To use it, just import network from file and point to a kgml file you downloaded from KEGG.